# Identify mid 20C Western male dress uniform: three button, large high lapels, trousers, white collar dark tie no hat

Tags: identification, uniform

can anybody identify the uniform on the photo? Thanks!
[image]

These are relatives of mine, and I was hoping to find out in which country they are based on the uniform. Should be US or Argentina, based on what I know. The photo could be from early 50's?
Male uniform, mid 20th century, mid coloured jacket with single breast buttoned high, with high large lapels.  Two top pockets, two waist pockets.  Clear waist line stitch.  Dark soft shoulder boards, single medium stripe and circular insignia on boards.  White shirt with inbuilt collar, both collars pinned.  Dark tie with a tight small knot. Pressed and creased trousers.  No hat.

Comment: Please provide everything you know about the individuals and details in the photo. Nationality, birth year(s), location, etc.

Comment: The asymmetric badges on the shirt lapel make it look not US. The lack of curl on the ensign's stripe makes it not look Argentine.  The blob on the shoulder straps above the ensigns bar does not look like a US or Argentine blob.

Comment: The asymmetry of the collar badges is consistent with a US Navy Service Corps uniform, but I cannot make out the details of the badge on the left collar to make out which service corps.  The rank looks like ensign or (possibly) warrant officer.

Comment: It appears to me to be the US Public Health Service, an Ensign.

Comment: Thanks for your replys! The main target was to identify the country and it seems to be the US. I doubt, IT would be possible get much mir information out of this picture...

Comment: @Mi3ch If you're doing family history research and have specific questions about your relatives, you might want to wander over to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/ . Are you familiar with Fold3?

Comment: @shoover Thank you for the tip! Unfortunately, I don't know much more than this photo (Not Sure, of the names remained the same). The only chance would be, that somebody would recognize the persones on the photo - almost impossible. The search at fold3 didn't provide matches