# Please help me identify this uniform and insignia from possibly the Utah Territorial Militia?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

[image]This person is Charles Robert Jones, my 3rd great-grandfather. He served in the Utah Territorial Militia during the Utah Black Hawk War. The year would be about 1866. Could this be the uniform and what do the markings mean? He emigrated from England in 1862 and may have even served in the Civil War.

Comment: Either a photo or a full description or both would be a great help.

Comment: Tips for verbose visual descriptions can be found in Wikipedia’s editing guides and models for verbose visual descriptions can be found in some past uniform identification questions.

Comment: Here's an example of appropriate verbose description: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59398/identify-mid-20c-western-male-dress-uniform-three-button-large-high-lapels-tr

Comment: Appears to me to be more of a fraternal organization's regalia rather than a military uniform.